# Disable/Enable WiFi driver

Tags: wireless, drivers

I use the command: 
Sudo modprobe iwlwifi (it removes WiFi module from the kernel) 
How can I return it? which command should I use? 
(if I shutdown and restart PC the driver is up and running)

Comment: Are you certain it's not `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`, that is, '-r' for remove?

Comment: Why you do it this way? There is no need to remove the driver for switching wifi off.

Comment: I tried using: sudo ifconfig wlan0 down (I used wlan3 since this is what I got  when I typed sudu ifconfig -a), but the WiFi driver is still up and I am connected to the AP. I would try the network manager, but I don't know how to use Network Manager. thank you

Answer (score 1):

To add the driver back again, simply do

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

This will load the driver again.
As already said in the comments, to disable WiFi, you do not need to remove the driver. A command like

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

will suffice. For wlan0, you will have to insert the actual name of your WiFi device. To bring WiFi back up, just do

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Kind regards.

Comment: It may not be always wlan0 and NM may get it up again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Network Manager, the correct way to disable/enable Wi-Fi is

```
nmcli nm wifi off
nmcli nm wifi on
```